# Save zip file in a different directory than the level at which code file is present

Tags: php, directory, zip

I have written a code to zip all the content of a given directory, the code runs perfectly but I want to save the zip file in a different directory from which I am calling the function.

Code:

```
$source = realpath('application');
$address = realpath('backup');
$destination = $address . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'download.zip';

if (file_exists($destination)) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}

Zip($source, $destination);

function Zip($source, $destination)
{
    if (!extension_loaded('zip') || !file_exists($source)) {
        return false;
    }

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if (!$zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)) {
        return false;
    }

    $source = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($source));

    if (is_dir($source) === true)
    {
        $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
            $file = str_replace('\\', '/', $file);

            // Ignore "." and ".." folders
            if( in_array(substr($file, strrpos($file, '/')+1), array('.', '..')) )
                continue;

            $file = realpath($file);

            if (is_dir($file) === true)
            {
                $zip->addEmptyDir(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file . '/'));
            }
            else if (is_file($file) === true)
            {
                $zip->addFromString(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file), file_get_contents($file));
            }
        }
    }
    else if (is_file($source) === true)
    {
        $zip->addFromString(basename($source), file_get_contents($source));
    }

    return $zip->close();
}
```

The zip file is not created for this code, but if I do this

```
$destination = 'zip.php';
```

The zip file is created.
What do I do to save the file in some other directory.

Comment: Have you checked write permissions on that directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure, backup dir is exists? Then only it will create Zip file inside backup folder. Append bellow code to your existing code

```
$address = realpath('backup');
if (!file_exists($address)){
    if (!mkdir($address, 0777, true)) {
            die('Failed to create folder.');
    }
}
```

Hope it will solve your problem. Or else check backup folder file access permissions.

Comment: Directory did exist, but the issue was about permissions. Thanks for the issue though.

Comment: Welcome, @JashParekh, Can you add +1 to my ans